# How to Find Out Which Program is Responsible for Outgoing Traffic on Certain Ports

Tags: networking, firewall

I have pfSense set up to block outgoing connections on ports that are not specified in a config. Now, looking through the firewall logs, I see various ports that are being used and blocked for outgoing traffic. I have access to the machine that is generating the outgoing traffic that is blocked.

I am able to see what ports Ubuntu is listening on using the command `netstat -nputw`. It also shows the program that is using the port which is what I'm looking for except for outgoing traffic. Does anybody know how I can tell what program is responsible for outgoing traffic on say port 6969?

Also, can I tell which program sends traffic to certain IP addresses?

Comment: [Here you can find the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/604998/monitor-tcp-traffic-on-specific-port/848966)

Answer (score 0):

the command you used shows for both outgoing and incoming traffic. If you add `-l` to your flags, then it would show listening ports. You also could have added a `-c`flag for continuous and then appended a  `| grep 6969` to see matching lines for 6969...

It would still been a little difficult to isolate only outgoing traffic from that...

`ss` offers more options to play with than netstat.

or something like nethogs presents that live data.
`apt-get install nethogs`

Answer (score 0):

Read `man lsof` and do

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:6969
```